# jquery mobile themeroller issue

Tags: jquery-mobile, jquery-mobile-themeroller

I'm designing an app using phonegap, and I wanted to use jquery mobile's ThemeRoller for making theme's for the different pages of the app. Anyways, my issue, first of all, is that the theme I create is not showing up on the pages. I removed the original jquery structure .css file and replaces it with the correct structure file, along with my theme .css file. Like this:

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/themes/TestTheme.css" />
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile.structure-1.3.1.min.css" />
```

I tried different things, like adding data-theme="a" into each of the different data-role's, but that didn't make any difference. Another thing that is confusing me however, is that when I download the .zip file, and I open up the index page to make sure the theme is being applied correctly, it doesn't have any kind of jquery structuring to it, it's just a plain white page with black text, with no input slider at all, and the buttons look like I've traveled back in time to Windows 95. Any ideas of what's happening?

Comment: did u download the images pack as well?

Comment: Well, that's in the zip folder, so I have that when I open the index page, but I don't include it into my project in eclipse, I'll give that a shot.

Comment: Okay, I added the whole themes folder into my project, which includes the images folder, and it still did not work in my app.